# Select data between string range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Employee`,

```
_________________________________
Id | name    |      salary                    
______________________________
1  | John    |   [1300 - 2000] 
_______________________________
2  | Aby     |   [600 - 1000] 
________________________________
3  | Mike    |   [1000 - 1500]
```

Salary column is `Nvarchar`

I want a Query/ Function/ SP in SQL , If I search for 1400 the output should be like as below

```
Id | name    |      salary                    
________________________________
1  | John    |   [1300 - 2000] 
_______________________________
3  | Mike    |   [1000 - 1500]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Salary column is Nvarchar`. That's a bug. If you have a from/to range you need to use two separate columns for the `From` and `To` values, with the *correct* type - integer or decimal depending on the values. Once you fix the bug writing the query becomes trivial

Comment: There's *no* reason to store value ranges as text, that string can't be queried or indexed. That string actually takes *more* space than two bigint or decimal columns. Even if that string came from a legacy application, it has to be converted to two separate values to allow querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store ranges in one column. But if You can't change it there is sollusion:

```
SELECT  [Id] , name, 
      ,[salary] 
  FROM [Test Database].[dbo].[test] where 
1700 >= RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(salary,0, CHARINDEX('-',salary)))) 
and 1700 <=  RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(salary, CHARINDEX('-', salary) + 1, LEN(salary))))
```

Comment: I used REPLACE function before SUBSTRING to replace "[" & " ] " with "" and it works fine. Thanks....

Comment: SELECT [Id] , name, ,[salary] FROM [Test Database].[dbo].[test] where 1700 >= RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(salary,0, CHARINDEX('-',salary)),'[',''))) and 1700 <= RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(salary, CHARINDEX('-', salary) + 1, LEN(salary)),']','')))

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract numeric values, and then cast to a numeric type :

```
declare @mySalary money;
set  @mySalary = 1400;

with Employee(ID, Name, Salary ) as
(
 select 1,'John','[1300 - 2000]' union all
 select 2,'Aby','[600 - 1000]'   union all
 select 3,'Mike','[1000 - 1500]'
), e2 as
(
select SUBSTRING(Salary,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Salary),CHARINDEX('-',Salary)-2) as Salary1,
       SUBSTRING(Salary,CHARINDEX('-',Salary)+1,CHARINDEX(']',Salary)-CHARINDEX('-',Salary)-1) as Salary2,
       e.*
  from Employee e
)
select ID, Name, Salary
  from e2
 where @mySalary between cast(Salary1 as money) and cast(Salary2 as money);

ID  Name    Salary
1   John    [1300 - 2000]
3   Mike    [1000 - 1500]
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=869196db73c07ad5d0ffc63169753b3c)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, name varchar(15), salary varchar(20));
declare @mySalary int = 1400;

insert into @tbl 
 select 1,'John','[1300 - 2000]' union all
 select 2,'Aby','[600 - 1000]'   union all
 select 3,'Mike','[1000 - 1500]'

select id, name, salary from (
    select id, name, salary,
           convert(int, substring(salary, openBrcktIdx + 1, hyphenIdx - openBrcktIdx - 2)) lowerBound,
           convert(int, substring(salary, hyphenIdx + 2, closeBrcktIdx - hyphenIdx - 2)) upperBound
    from (
        select *,
               charindex('-', salary) hyphenIdx,
               charindex('[', salary) openBrcktIdx,
               charindex(']', salary) closeBrcktIdx
        from @tbl
    ) t
) t where @mySalary between lowerBound and upperBound
```

Answer (score 1):

declare @var1 int =1400

select * from
(select *,replace(SUBSTRING(salary,0,CHARINDEX('-',salary,0)),'[','') as Splitted1,
replace(SUBSTRING(salary,CHARINDEX('-',salary,0)+1,len(salary)-1),']','') as Splitted2
from employee 
) as t1
where @var1>=Splitted1 and @var1<=Splitted2

https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler